# matlab's isempty for a std::vector ( c++)

Tags: c++, matlab, stl

What would be the most efficient way to implement a matlab like function to check if an std::vector is empty?

here's a sample code of what i am trying to

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    tmp = x[i];
    if ((tmp > max) || (tmp < max)) {
        indexout.push_back(tmp);
    }

    if ((tmp < min) && (tmp > max)) {
        indexin.push_back(tmp);
    }
}

if (isempty(indexin)) {   //heres the part i don't know how to do
    //do something
}
else
```

Comment: `std::vector` already *has* an `empty()` function. What's wrong with that?

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`vector::empty()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/empty/).

```
if(indexin.empty()) {
}
```